# Let $u_m=L(v_m)-v_m$ where $L$ is the left shift operator and $v_m$ a convergent sequence of $\ell^2$ then $\left\| u_m \right\|_{\ell^1}$ is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $L : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ be the left shift operator $(v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots) \mapsto (v_2,v_3,v_4,\dots) $

Let $\{v_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of $\ell^2$ such that $v_m \to v$ (in $\ell^2$ metric)

Let $u_m=L(v_m)-v_m$

I would like to know if 
$$
\sup_{m \in \mathbb{N}}
\left\| u_m \right\|_{\ell^1}
<\infty
$$

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: well the fact that the sequence converges seems to not help for your problem (unless you wanted a statement about the $\limsup$)

Comment: any information about my question in welcome... any suggest? thanks

Comment: well, if your question is well stated, then it is equivalent to ask if the operator $x\in\ell^2\mapsto L(x)-x\in\ell^1$ is bounded.

Comment: i think my question is weaker because i don't need a convergent sequence but only bounded, anyhow thanks @Surb

Comment: well if there exists $x\in\ell^2$ such that $L(x)-x\notin \ell^1$ then let $v_n=x$ for all $x$ and you get a counter example. If $L(x)-x\in \ell^1$ for all $x\in \ell^2$, then $u_m\in\ell^1$ for all $m$ and by continuity, its limit is also in $\ell^1$.

Comment: ok @Surb thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in general seems to be no:

Define $v_m = \left(v^{(m)}_n\right)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^2$ as:

$$v^{(m)}_n = \begin{cases}
\frac1n,  & \text{if $n$ is a perfect square and $n \le m^2$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

We have $v_m \xrightarrow{m\to\infty} 0$:

$$\left\|v_m \right\|_2^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|v^{(m)}_n\right|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^m \frac1{k^2} \xrightarrow{m\to\infty} 0$$

However,

$$u_m = \left(v^{(m)}_2 - v^{(m)}_1, v^{(m)}_3 - v^{(m)}_2, \ldots, v^{(m)}_{m^2} - v^{(m)}_{m^2-1}, -v^{(m)}_{m^2}, 0, 0, \ldots \right) = \left(1, 0, 0, \frac{1}{2}, \ldots ,\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{m}, 0, 0\ldots \right)$$

$$\|u_m\|_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{m^2 - 1}\left|v^{(m)}_{k+1} - v^{(m)}_k\right| + \left|v^{(m)}_{m^2}\right| \ge \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k} \xrightarrow{m\to\infty} +\infty$$

Therefore, the set $\big\{\|u_m\|_1 : m\in\mathbb{N}\big\}$ is unbounded.

Comment: ok @mechanodroid  thanks for your helping again